# Kernel swap-related errors syslog flood

Tags: kernel, swap, syslog

Operating system: Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit Cinnamon

Kernel version: 4.4.0-62-generic #83

Swap: partition; 8GB

Relevant hardware:

- [SSHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive); [ST1000LM014](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/consumer/upgrade/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/) with 8GB [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NAND_flash) Flash
- 2x 4GB DDR3 1600 MHz; [M471B5173EB0-YK0](http://www.memorybenchmark.net/ram.php?ram=Samsung%20M471B5173EB0-YK0%204GB&id=6521)

I have just taken a look at one computer's:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

And I found out, it is completely filled up with these kernel swap-related errors.

First, there are myriads of these:

```
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049442] swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 438000004300
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049444] BUG: Bad page map in process ScriptStreamerT  pte:87000000860000 pmd:359a0067
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049446] addr:00007fb40fa03000 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:ffff8802407251e0 index:ed
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049452] file:libplds4.so fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049455] CPU: 2 PID: 8036 Comm: ScriptStreamerT Tainted: G    B           4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049457] Hardware name: LENOVO 20354/Lancer 5A5, BIOS 9BCN31WW 04/20/2015
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049458]  0000000000000286 00000000b31f5a18 ffff88022aacfa58 ffffffff813f7c63
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049460]  00007fb40fa03000 ffff8800a69debb8 ffff88022aacfaa8 ffffffff811bdcef
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049463]  ffff88022aacfa80 ffffffff811d4e40 0000438000004300 0087000000860000
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049466] Call Trace:
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049468]  [<ffffffff813f7c63>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049472]  [<ffffffff811bdcef>] print_bad_pte+0x1df/0x2a0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049474]  [<ffffffff811d4e40>] ? swap_info_get+0xb0/0xd0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049478]  [<ffffffff811bf678>] unmap_page_range+0x468/0x7a0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049481]  [<ffffffff811bfa2d>] unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xe0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049484]  [<ffffffff811c04f1>] unmap_vmas+0x51/0xa0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049487]  [<ffffffff811c9a77>] exit_mmap+0xa7/0x170
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049491]  [<ffffffff8107e0a7>] mmput+0x57/0x130
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049494]  [<ffffffff81083f2a>] do_exit+0x27a/0xb00
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049499]  [<ffffffff8110045c>] ? __unqueue_futex+0x2c/0x60
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049501]  [<ffffffff81100f7e>] ? futex_wait+0x16e/0x280
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049506]  [<ffffffff8119f41b>] ? release_pages+0xdb/0x2b0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049509]  [<ffffffff81084833>] do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049513]  [<ffffffff810909b2>] get_signal+0x292/0x600
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049518]  [<ffffffff8102e567>] do_signal+0x37/0x6f0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049522]  [<ffffffff8113d15f>] ? seccomp_phase1+0x9f/0x280
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049526]  [<ffffffff81833e16>] ? __schedule+0x3b6/0xa30
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049530]  [<ffffffff8100320c>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x8c/0xd0
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049532]  [<ffffffff81003c6e>] syscall_return_slowpath+0x4e/0x60
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.049536]  [<ffffffff81838750>] int_ret_from_sys_call+0x25/0x8f
```

And after that comes sort of a list of these errors:

```
Feb 14 12:14:52 RB-NB-Mint kernel: [187383.053016] swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 588000005800
```

Note, that this computer suspends to memory very often, where *very often* means like 10-20 a day. I point this out as a possible correlation with this problem.

Can the swap partition be *broken* or something?

Comment: I don't think the swap partition can be broken as such. The disk can be failing, or the memory can be failing, or it can be a kernel bug, or a BIOS (firmware) bug that causes data corruption in the kernel. The messages indicate page table corruption, I think what's corrupted is actually data structures that always remain in RAM. Beware that you may have corrupted data. Run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/) and try a more recent kernel if possible.

Comment: @Gilles RAM is OK. Thank you for your reply. As I don't have a spare HDD to replace SSHD, that is probably causing it, I turned off swap entirely. As soon as I have the new HDD, I will replace it.